# ajax causing mysql duplicate entry?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I am using the following ajax script to run my MySQL function and insert a entry into my table. Its working fine except it is duplicating the entry twice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#support1').click(function(e) {
        var sel_stud = "support1";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/run_support_log.php",
            data: 'theOption=' + sel_stud,
            success: function() {
                $('#support_content').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

MySQL:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'config.php';

$type = $_POST['theOption'];
if($type == "support1"){
$type = "Phone Support";
}



$random = 'S' . substr( md5(rand()), 0, 7); echo $random;


$query = "INSERT INTO supplier_log (id, reference, user_id, date, activity_type) VALUES ('', '$reference','{$_SESSION['id']}', now(), '$type')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result) {
    echo 'success';
}

?>
```

please can someone show me where abouts I am going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your script is included only once in the page? I am quite much sure it is included twice.

Comment: Is the `ajax` called twice?

Comment: @Tushar no I only have one occurrence of the ajax :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the the line

```
include 'config.php';
```

isn't including your script a second time?

It shouldn't, cause it would make an infinite loop. But check it just in case.

Comment: thank you I forgot that my include 'config.php' file was including my jquery.php file where the ajax was bein stored, this has now solved my problem. thanks

Comment: this is my first problem that i solved for someone on this site :) i am more than welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You insert the element with id = ''.
So every element has the same id.

May be you change

```
"INSERT INTO supplier_log (id, reference, user_id, date, activity_type) VALUES ('', '$reference','{$_SESSION['id']}', now(), '$type')";
```

by

```
"INSERT INTO supplier_log (reference, user_id, date, activity_type) VALUES ( '$reference','{$_SESSION['id']}', now(), '$type')";
```

and let the id be generated by MySQL

Comment: thanks for your suggestion however it still duplicates the entry even if I change my code to what you suggested